# Google Forms Script Editor to send emails based on answer

Tags: google-apps-script

I use a Google Form to track employee hours and jobs completed for a mechanical services small business.  The guys want to be able to get an email of their responses to track their own hours and ensure they put everything in correctly.  I don't want them to have to enter their email every time or log in - they complete this on their phones and want to keep it as simple and less repetitive as possible.

I've looked on a lot of places around here and have (what I think) is the basis of a good code in Google Script Editor.  I had it working to send an automated email, but when I added the information in the message it didn't work.  I used some other examples out there and tried to put a few together to make it work.  I'd appreciate any help critiquing this code and helping me figure out why it isn't working.  I'm new to this and can't seem to figure it out.  Thanks.

```
function EmailTimeSheetCMS(e){
var name = e.values [1];
var ReplyEmail = "__________@yahoo.com"
var Email1 = "__________@gmail.com"
var WorkOrder = e.values[2];
var date = e.values[3];
var location = e.values[4];
var jobdescription = e.values[5];
var notes = e.values[6];
var vendors = e.values[7];
var starttime = e.values[8];
var endtime = e.values[9];
var otherworkers = e.values[10]
var status = e.values [11];
var reghrs = e.values[12];
var othrs = e.values[13];
var tools = e.values[15];
var message = "You entered the following information" + "\nDate " + date + "\nWork Order # " + WorkOrder +  "\nLocation " + location +  "\nStart Time" + starttime +  "\nEnd Time " + endtime +  "\nRegular Hours worked" + reghrs + "\nOvertime Hours " + othrs +  "\nJob Description " + jobdescription + "\nNotes " + notes +  "\nVendors and Invoices " + vendors +  "\nOther Workers Present " + otherworkers + "\nTools Used " + tools + "\nJob Status " + status ;



if(name = 'Bill')
{MailApp.sendEmail(Email1, ReplyEmail, "CMS Time Submission - Bill", message) }

else if(name = 'Scott')
{MailApp.sendEmail(ReplyEmail, ReplyEmail, "CMS Time Submission - Scott", message)
} }
```

Answer (score 1):

On a first glance I see a potential flaw.

In the if condition i.e when you say

```
if (name = 'Bill')
```

it assigns 'Bill' to the variable name.

could you try writing it as

```
if(name == 'Bill')
```

and see if it works.

And when posting a question next time, it is always a good practice to enter the error message you get. Or at least the 'Execution transcript' available under the View in menu bar

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I made that correction.  The error message said the following: "Script function not found: EmailTimeSheetCMS".  The execution transcript says "TypeError: Cannot read property "values" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"